# How to programmatically detect deleted files?

Tags: tfs, detect, delete-file

In Team Foundation, you can ask Team Explorer to show deleted files by doing this:

> Tools > Options > Source Control >
>   Visual Team Foundation Server > Show
>   deleted items in the Source Control
>   Explorer.

My question is how do you do the same thing programmatically?

I am developing a synchronisation tool, and I need to detected deleted files in TFS. Workspace.Get(...) returns only non-deleted files.

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Visual Studio folder in your start menu and start up a Visual Studio Command Prompt from the "Visual Studio Tools" subfolder.

The command you want to run is:

```
tf dir /server:myserver $/myproject /recursive /deleted
```

(where myserver and myproject are your server and project)

use "tf help" for general info, "tfs help dir" for more help on this command, or google on "tf.exe" for more info.

Comment: Hi Jason;
Thank you for help. I experimented with the command and it adds a deletionId next to the deleted items.
Do you know if it's possible to the same thing with the managed API? or with any other API for that matter.
Thank you.

Comment: I would imagine so, but I haven't used that part of the API, so can't answer you authoritatively.

Comment: I finally found out how:
ItemSet itemSet = sourceControl.GetItems(path, VersionSpec.Latest, RecursionType.OneLevel, DeletedState.Any, ItemType.Any);

TY.

Comment: HOw can I do the "undo" action or get-retrieve deleted files?

Comment: @Kiquenet: The easiest way to work with deleted files is to enable Tools > Options > Source Control > Visual Studio Team Foundation > Show deleted items in the Source Control Explorer. Then deleted items appear in the Source Control window and you can Get History, Get Specific Version, Undelete, etc. on the item from its context menu.

Answer (score 0):

The VersionControlServer.QueryHistory API will give you access to the changesets which will contain all version control operations including deletes.